# XCode does not stop on Debug Break Point

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it related or not after installing Xcode 7.1, it does not stop on break points.
I tried some tips but none of them works.

What might be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. From the Xcode menu select Preferences
2. Select the "Locations" panel
3. Click the disclosure arrow (->) next to Derived Data
4. The DerivedData folder opens in Finder.  Delete it.
5. Recompile.

Usually this helps.